# Did I kill my flashdrive?

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-17.04

I have a SanDisk Ultra 64GB (SDDD3-064G-G46) flash drive, which I haven't used in a while. Today I plugged it into my computer (I use Ubuntu Linux 17.04, but dual boot into Windows 10) and found it unable to load the drive. It even crashed the disks application when I tried to inspect it further.

I then booted into Windows 10, but I was also unable to inspect it there. I followed [this tutorial](https://windowsexplored.com/2012/06/11/making-my-unusable-usb-stick-usable-again/) to identify the causes, but DISKPART wouldn't start. I know that the drive is the problem because removing it caused diskpart to immediately open.

This drive caused two OS's drive inspection programs to fail. I think the drive is just broken, but I would be very happy if you could help me fix it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @DavidPostill why is this marked as duplicate? In the question you link to they are obviously able to open DISKPART, it's in their screenshot. This is not the case here, which is the exact problem I am having. I'm trying to get to a place where that post is useful

Comment: I believe your drive is essentially dead. However, there are a couple of suggestions in the answers to the dupe that *may* help you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try booting into WinPE (recovery mode), per the tutorial? Pretty easy, through Settings->Update&Security->Advanced_Startup, or boot from a DVD or (working) USB stick *with* a Windows image.

From recovery mode, you can open a command-prompt, under a limited set of OS features, which often works better for disk type issues, and use diskpart, similarly.

Another good way is to build a "super boot disk", there are a few out there, which allow you to boot from a DVD/USB stick into DOS, numerous flavors of WinPE, etc.

FreeDOS is probably the easiest, since it supports 2TB drives natively and through its FDISK version.  If you go MS-DOS, you have to boot a Win95b/Win98 version or above, in order to have > 2GB support with FDISK.

Ultimately, your "gut feel" on the broken part is probably accurate, but this would help you feel a bit better about verification.
They're more fragile than some would think, I try to buy ones where there's some sort of "cap" to protect it from some static discharge anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I booted into command line (which I was unaware was an option. It looks very weird) and found the same results. I think I'm going to call it quits on this one. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yep, the command line is a bit odd the way it's laid out, but handy for recovery and random stuff like this.  Good call on the drive, definitely sounds like it's a goner, or close enough to call now anyway.